# Installing new application

Tags: installation

I got few linux applications from a chip(MAGAZINE) cd I wanted to try (especially vlc and a few others), but didn't know how to install them. I saw a button named install it gives me some info but I can't install things like I used to with windows. I installed a few with software center, but my network connection is slow and it took me more than a hour to download an install a 10mb software. So please tell me how to install such software.